# How to create sub groups in sonata admin

Tags: sonata, usergroups

I'm using symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle. I have user management in two categories. I have created a group named User Management. Is it possible to create 2 subgroups inside the User Management group with the 2 categories in sonata admin?